# How to load images from firebase to carousel react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to get some images from firebase storage loaded into a [react-responsive-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-carousel). The problem is that only 1 or 2 or even none of the images are loaded (there are at least 10 images). This is what I'm trying:

```
const [imagenes, setImagenes] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
        const fetchedImagenes = [];

        firebase.storage().ref().child('PR/Gallery').listAll().then(function (result) {
            result.items.forEach(function (itemRef) {
                itemRef.getDownloadURL().then(function (link) {
                    const fetchedImagen = link
                    fetchedImagenes.push(fetchedImagen)
                })
            });
            setImagenes(fetchedImagenes)
        })

}, [])
```

And this is the `carousel` code:

```
<Carousel dynamicHeight={true}>
    {imagenes.map(imagen => {
        return <div>
            <img src={imagen} />
        </div>
    })}
</Carousel>
```

My guess is that the `imagenes` array is not filled when I show the images, so is there any way that I can wait for the `imagenes` array to be filled and then show the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're now calling `setImagenes(fetchedImagenes)` before any of the `fetchedImagenes.push(fetchedImagen)` has been called, so you're setting an empty array.

The quick fix is to set the array to the state whenever a download URL is determined by moving it into the `then` callback:

```
firebase.storage().ref().child('PR/Gallery').listAll().then(function (result) {
    result.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
        itemRef.getDownloadURL().then((link) => {
            const fetchedImagen = link
            fetchedImagenes.push(fetchedImagen)
            setImagenes(fetchedImagenes)
        })
    });
})
```

This will work, but may result in some flicker as you're updating the UI whenever any download URL is determined.

If you want to only update the state/UI once, you're looking for `Promise.all` and it'll be something like:

```
firebase.storage().ref().child('PR/Gallery').listAll().then(function (result) {
    const promises = result.items.map((itemRef) => itemRef.getDownloadURL());
    Promise.all(promises).then((urls) =>
        setImagenes(urls)
    });
})
```